# What is conceptually wrong with get-date|Write-Host($_)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand Powershell, but find somethings not so intuitive. What I understand of it is that in the pipeline objects are passed, instead of traditionally text. And $_ refers to the current object in the pipeline. Then, why is the following not working:

```
get-date|Write-Host "$_"
```

The errormessage is:

Write-Host : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not matc
h any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:10
+ get-date|Write-Host $_
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (10-9-2014 15:17:00:PSObject) [Write-Host], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$_` is the current single item in the pipeline. To write each item in the pipeline you would write

```
get-data | foreach { Write-Host $_ }
```

Or in the short form

```
get-data |% { Write-Host $_ }
```

Conceptually, Foreach is a cmdlet that receives a function parameter, a pipeline input and applies the function on each item of the pipeline. You can't just write code with `$_` - you need to have a function explicitly states that it agrees to receive pipeline input

Comment: See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847902.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx for more information on defining pipeline inputs

Comment: OK, I kind of get this, but not entirely. According to "get-help Write-Host -parameter *", positional parameter -Object accepts pipeline input and indeed "get-date|Write-Host" works. So then, what's the difference with using $_ as a substitute for the pipeline input and the command using the pipeline input directly. Is it just because $_ is an array (hence the foreach is needed) and in that case would you be able to get the first item like $_[0]?

Comment: While Write-Host is willing to get it's input from the pipeline (i.e. the Object parameter is automatically bound to the pipeline if not specified), what you did with `Write-Host $_` was to specify the object, so it was bound to `$_` and not the pipeline. But `$_` is not really the pipeline data - it's a variable which is only defined by the foreach function for the function you give it

Answer (score 0):

> And $_ refers to the current object in the pipeline

Indeed, the [automatic **`$_`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) **refers to the current pipeline object, but *only in [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ ... }`***, notably those passed to the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlets.

**Outside of script blocks it has *no* meaningful value**.

Therefore, the *immediate* fix to your command is the following:

```bash
Get-Date | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

However, note that:

- [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is [is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file.
- To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g, `$value`, instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375). To explicitly print only to the display *but with rich formatting*, use `Out-Host`.

Therefore, if merely *outputting* each pipeline input object is the goal, `Get-Date | ForEach-Object { $_ }` would do, where the `ForEach-Object` call is *redundant* if each input object is to simply be *passed through* (without transformation); that is, in the latter case just `Get-Date` would do.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> get-date|Write-Host "$_"
> ```

As noted, the use of `$_` in this context is pointless, but the reason for the error message you saw is *unrelated* to that problem:

Instead, **the reason for the error is that you're mistakenly trying to provide input to [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) *both* via the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) `Get-Date | Write-Host ...` *and* by way of an *argument* (`... | Write-Host "..."`)**

- Given that the *argument* (`"$_"`) (positionally) binds to the `-Object` parameter, the *pipeline input* then has no parameter left to bind to, which causes the error at hand.