# PowerShell to delete current users folder and files

Tags: directory, filesystems, powershell-2.0, delete-file, localdatacache

Want to delete any files of folders name beginning with word "Leap" in file location localdata\Microsoft_Corporation\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [powershell - delete files using list of file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494686/powershell-delete-files-using-list-of-file-names)