# redirecting test-path output to text file

Tags: powershell, write-host

The txt file is just a bunch of UNC paths, i am trying to get a list of UNC paths from this text file put into another text file after the test-path is validated.  it shows the validated paths on screen but the text file does not populate.

```
$cfgs = Get-Content .\cfgpath.txt
$cfgs | % {
  if (Test-Path $_) { write-host "$_" | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\1.txt -Append }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Write-Host` only writes to the console.  I believe what you want there is `Write-Output`.

```
$cfgs = Get-Content .\cfgpath.txt
$cfgs | % {
  if (Test-Path $_) { write-output "$_" | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\1.txt -Append }
}
```

Additionally you can just omit the `Write-Output` and that works too.

```
$cfgs = Get-Content .\cfgpath.txt
$cfgs | % {
  if (Test-Path $_) { "$_" | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\1.txt -Append }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Zam's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60532941/45375) with **background information**:

- **[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) writes to the *host***<sup>[1]</sup> (typically, the console aka terminal), which  *bypasses* PowerShell's [success output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) and therefore ***sends nothing trough the pipeline***.

  - See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375) for when `Write-Host` is appropriate; in short: you should generally only **use it for *display-only* output**.
- **[`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) is the appropriate cmdlet for producing *data* output**, but **it is rarely necessary**, because **you can rely on PowerShell's convenient *implicit* output behavior**, as shown in Zam's answer and explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375).

---

Also, **your command will perform much better** if you simply **pipe the `%` ([`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)) command's output *as a whole* to a *single* `Out-File` call**, rather than calling `Out-File -Append` *for each input path*.

Instead of using `%` with conditional explicit output, you can more elegantly implement your command with the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet:

```bash
Get-Content .\cfgpath.txt |
  Where-Object { Test-Path $_ } |
  Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\1.txt
```

Also note that **for saving *strings* to a file it is more efficient to use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)** instead of
`Out-File`, though note that in *Windows PowerShell* the default output character encoding differs (no longer a concern in PowerShell [Core] 6+, which consistently defaults to BOM-less UTF-8); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375) for when to choose which cmdlet.

By contrast, **`Out-File` and `>` (its effective alias) use PowerShell's formatting system to write *for-display* representations of any non-string input objects to the output file**, the same way that output renders to the display by default.
In other words: **To save objects to a file in a way that is suitable for later *programmatic processing*, you need to use a structured file format**, such as CSV ([`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)) or JSON ([`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json), combined with `Set-Content`).

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell 5.0 and higher, `Write-Host` now writes to a new stream, the information stream (number `6`), which by default prints to the host. See [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).
Therefore, a `6>` redirection now technically does allow you to send `Write-Host` output through the pipeline (though doing so is not a good idea) or capture / redirect it; e.g.,

`Write-Host hi 6>&1 | % { "[$_]" }`. Note that the type of the objects output by this redirection is [`System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord).</sup>