# PowerShell. Convert Comma Separated Values Into Separate Objects

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a PowerShell script in Azure DevOps Pipeline that outputs a list of possible IP address that Web App can use:

```
$deploymentOutputs=(ConvertFrom-Json '$(deploymentOutputs)')
$possibleOutboundIpAddresses=$($deploymentOutputs.possibleOutboundIpAddresses.value)
Write-Host $possibleOutboundIpAddresses
```

Output looks like this:

```
23.89.272.2,52.165.130.123,40.222.30.223
```

How can I transform the PowerShell script to output not comma separated values, but rather output those values as Each-Object?

```
23.89.272.2
52.165.130.123
40.222.30.223
```

Ideally, I'd love to also be able to add custom text before the values:

```
IP1 - 23.89.272.2
IP2 - 52.165.130.123
IP3 - 40.222.30.223
```

**EDIT:**
The above examples were oversimplification of what I'm trying to do. What I really need to do is to create Azure DevOps variable for each entry in that output. I actually need to perform this PowerShell commands based on the number of IPs and values of IPs:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$IP1;]23.89.272.2"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$IP2;]52.165.130.123"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$IP3;]40.222.30.223"
```

Comment: As an aside: To avoid a distraction, can I suggest you remove the `Write-Host ` prefixes from your commands?

Comment: Write-Host is actually mandatory for creating Azure DevOps Variable from PowerShell.

Comment: For my own edification: Why? What happens if you write to the _success output stream_, which is where _data_ should go? `Write-Host` output is usually only captured by _outside callers_ that call PowerShell via its CLI, but so is success output.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for general information about `Write-Host` vs. `Write-Output` / _implicit_ output. In short: don't use `Write-Host` to output _data_ (return values). Removing the `WriteHost ` prefix _implicitly_ outputs the values.

Comment: Once I inspected the answer I realized that the rules are created by default. I was too quick to ask that question. I don't think any one would need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `String.Split()` method:

```
$possibleOutboundIpAddresses.Split(",")
```

or the `-split` regex operator:

```
$possibleOutboundIpAddresses -split ','
```

---

If you want them as properties of an object, you could use `ConvertFrom-Csv`:

```
$ipAddressObject = $possibleOutboundIpAddresses |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header IP1,IP2,IP3
```

Although this might not be the best strategy if `$possibleOutboundIpAddresses` can have a variable number of values

---

For generating the Azure DevOps variable declarations you could do something like:

```
function ConvertTo-AzureVsoIPVariable {
    $c = 1
    $input -split ',' |ForEach-Object {
      '##vso[task.setvariable variable=$IP{0};]{1}' -f $c++, $_
    }
}
```

Then use like:

```
$possibleOutboundIpAddresses | ConvertTo-AzureVsoIPVariable
```