# Issue with replacing a value of cell with returned variable - Incorrect formatting?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, hashtable

I'm currently struggling with some of the bits and pieces in my code.

I've got a SQL query that runs within powershell, that works fine, and dumps data into CSV - that's all working good.
Then, I'm importing that data into Powershell.

`$csv = Import-Csv -Path "$Path" | where {$_.Fullname -ne "System created."} #this filtering is done to sort incosistent data.`

And then I'm actually struggling, as I am carrying out some checks, and would like to replace a user's PIN number with a Manager's ID number.

```
Write-Host "initializing loop to go through each element"
 foreach ($row in $csv)
    {
    if(($row.primarypin.length -lt 1) -or ($row.primarypin.length -gt 5) -or ($row.primarypin -contains 'T') -or ($row.primarypin -contains 'X'))
        {
         Write-Host "Doing Primary Check" -BackgroundColor Green
         Write-Host $row.primarypin.Length
         Write-Host $row.FullName
         try{
         $getTempUserUsername = $row.name
         Write-Host "Replacing UserID with their Manager" -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor Cyan
         $getUsersManager = Get-ADUser -identity $getTempUserUsername -Properties department, Manager | Select-Object Manager
         Write-Host "Replacing with String $getUsersManager"
         $row.primarypin = $null
         $row.primarypin -replace $null, $getUsersManager
         }
         catch{
            Write-Host "Replacing With a Cannot find User in AD" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
            $row.primarypin -replace "Cannnot find user, this is a system user."
         }
         }
   else
        {
            Write-Host "Went directly to the else loop" -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor Yellow
            foreach($dataset in $row)
            {
                Write-Host "$dataset"

            }
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that whenever i'm trying to do a replace, It does seem to replace it within console, however doesn't seem to be saving it correctly to CSV file (which i'm then mailing, but already got that part correctly).

```
Remove-Item $path
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

So everytime I return the dataset It comes back as

```
"@{name=adnameexample; FullName=Lastname, Firstname; ColourCost=0.21600; Colour Pages Printed=13; primarypin=; Office=London; Department Number=}"
```

In this scenario I'd love for the primarypin to be returned as the manager's ID.
(I'm also trying to use try/catch in case there is some issue".

Has anyone got some idea on how to replace the data within that particular cell?

Please help guide me, wizards!

Comment: `Write-Host "$dataset"` -> `$dataset`. The `""` quotes forces PowerShell to convert the `$dataset` object to a string

Comment: Note that `Write-Host` output goes straight to the console - it is meant for _display_ output, not for writing _data_; to output _data_, use `Write-Output`, or, better yet, _implicit_ output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by *Manager's ID*

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Given that `Write-Host` uses simple `.ToString()` stringification anyway, that usually makes no difference; e.g. `$o = Get-Process -ID $PID;Write-Host "$o"; Write-Host $o`. (It can make a difference if the object is enumerable: `$o = @{ foo = 1 };Write-Host "$o"; Write-Host $o`)

Answer (score 0):

First, this command returns an object with a manager property

```
$getUsersManager = Get-ADUser -identity $getTempUserUsername -Properties department, Manager | Select-Object Manager
```

It seems you want just the value so add `-Expandproperty` to the `Select-Object` command. Just making sure you know, it will be a distinguished name. If you want just the name you'd need to look the manager up or extract it with regex. Also, why pull the department property if it's not being used? The new line can look like

```
$getUsersManager = Get-ADUser -identity $getTempUserUsername -Properties Manager | Select-Object -Expandproperty Manager
```

To just extract the name from the distinguished name here is one way.

```
$getUsersManager = $getUsersManager -replace '^.*?=(.*?),[a-z]{2}=.*$','$1'
```

Next, when you do the replace you also need to set it back to the primary pin. I would remove the set to `$null` and just replace whatever is in there, even if it's nothing, with the manager.

```
$row.primarypin = $row.primarypin -replace '.+', $getUsersManager
```

Comment: The `CN` can contain commas if users are listed as `LastName, FirstName` in the directory. `$getUsersManager = 'CN=Doe\, John,OU=Site,DC=domain,DC=com'` is an example. Safer alternative is something like `'^.*?=(.*?),[a-z]{2}=.*$','$1'`