# How to create a number from text with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have managed to parse a webpage with powershell and retrieve the text information I need with this code:

```
$searchClass = "dfx-technicalSentimentCard__signal"
$myURI = "https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$req = Invoke-Webrequest -URI $myURI
$req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName($searchClass) | %{Write-Host $_.innerhtml}
```

Now I would like to create a variable containing a number created from the text with Bullish=1, Bearish=2, Mixed=3

Example
If the result of my code is:

```
Mixed
Mixed
Mixed
Mixed
Bullish
Bullish
Bullish
Bearish
Mixed
Bearish
Mixed
Mixed
Bearish
Bearish
Mixed
Bullish
Bullish
Mixed
Bearish
Bullish
Bullish
Mixed
Bullish
Bullish
```

The number would be `333311123233223113211311`

Thank you mklement0 for your solution.
Here is the working code:

```
 $searchClass = "dfx-technicalSentimentCard__signal"
$myURI = "https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 <# using TLS 1.2 is vitally important #>
$req = Invoke-Webrequest -URI $myURI
$signals = @()
$req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName($searchClass) | %{$signals += $_.innerhtml}
$profile = -join $(switch ($signals) {
    'Mixed'   { 3 }
    'Bullish' { 1 }
    'Bearish' { 2 }
    default   { throw "Unexpected string: $_" }
})
```

Thank you Esperento57 for adding a function, this works and it is a cleaner solution:

```
function transform([string] $signals)
{
     switch ($signals) {
    'Mixed'   { '3' }
    'Bullish' { '1' }
    'Bearish' { '2' }
    default   { ''  }
    }

}

$searchClass = "dfx-technicalSentimentCard__signal"
$profile=""
$myURI = "https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$req = Invoke-Webrequest -URI $myURI
$req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName($searchClass) | %{$profile+=transform $_.innerhtml}

$profile
```

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With open-ended mappings, the most maintainable solution is probably a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement:

```
$strings = 
  'Mixed',
  'Mixed',
  'Mixed',
  'Mixed',
  'Bullish',
  'Bullish',
  'Bullish',
  'Bearish',
  'Mixed',
  'Bearish',
  'Mixed',
  'Mixed',
  'Bearish',
  'Bearish',
  'Mixed',
  'Bullish',
  'Bullish',
  'Mixed',
  'Bearish',
  'Bullish',
  'Bullish',
  'Mixed',
  'Bullish',
  'Bullish'

-join $(switch ($strings) {
    'Mixed'   { 3 }
    'Bullish' { 1 }
    'Bearish' { 2 }
    default   { throw "Unexpected string: $_" }
})
```

Note the unary form of `-join`, the [string-joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join), which  directly concatenates the (stringified) outputs from the `switch` statement, passed as an operand to `-join` via `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of replace statements

```
$text = @'
Mixed Mixed Mixed Mixed Bullish Bullish Bullish Bearish Mixed Bearish Mixed Mixed Bearish Bearish Mixed Bullish Bullish Mixed Bearish Bullish Bullish Mixed Bullish Bullish
'@

$text -replace '\s' -replace 'Mixed','3' -replace 'Bullish','1' -replace 'Bearish','2'

333311123233223113211311
```

Comment: Makes sense with single-line input (+1); unfortunately, the lack of formatting in the original revision of the question disguised that the input is likely an _array_ of elements - that said, your solution should still work.

Comment: I see, but you think it would still work? I'll have to see. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke - it wouldn't work as-is, but `(-join $text) -replace 'Mixed','3'  ...` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Variation with a function :

```
function transform([string] $signals)
{
     switch ($signals) {
    'Mixed'   { '3' }
    'Bullish' { '1' }
    'Bearish' { '2' }
    default   { ''  }
    }

}

$searchClass = "dfx-technicalSentimentCard__signal"
$profile=""
$myURI = "https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$req = Invoke-Webrequest -URI $myURI
$req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName($searchClass) | %{$profile+=transform $_.innerhtml}

$profile
```