# Powershell issue getting variable inside quote

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This may be as noob question but how do i get a variable into quotes

```
Write-host 
$string1 = Read-Host

Write-host $string1
```

If i typed abc for write it will show abc.

how to i get it to show "abc"

doing "$string1" would just show as "$string" and not the value of it in quotes

Answer (score 1):

The enclosing `"` characters in `"$string1"` have *syntactic* function and are therefore *stripped* during parsing.

To make such characters a *part of the data*, you must embed *escaped* versions of them (`` `" ``):

```
PS> "`"$string1`"" # assume that $string1 contains verbatim: foo
"foo"
```

`` ` `` is PowerShell's general escape character; in the context of `"..."` strings ([expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)) you can use `` `" `` and `""` interchangeably.

Also note that the command above relies on PowerShell's *implicit output feature* - no need for [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), unless you explicitly want to write to the *display only*, without PowerShell's rich output formatting - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for more information.