# How to access last argument in PowerShell script (args)

Tags: powershell, args

I have following code:

```
foreach ($arg in $args) {
        Write-Host "Arg: $arg";
        $param1=$args[0]
}
Write-host "Number of args: " $args.Length
write-host Last Arg is: "$($args.count)"
```

I get this, when I run it:

```
./print_last_arg.ps1 a b c
Arg: a
Arg: b
Arg: c
Number of args:  3
Last Arg is: 3
```

What I would like to have is name of last argument,  so:

```
Last Arg is: 3
```

should be:

```
Last Arg is: c
```

Sorry for such a stupid question but I am totally begginer in PS and cannot google the result...

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PowerShell supports *negative* indices to refer to elements from the *end* of a collection, starting with `-1` to refer to the *last* element**, `-2` to the penultimate (second to last) one, and so on.

Therefore, use `$args[-1]` to refer to the last argument passed.

For more information, see the conceptual [about_Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) help topic.

---

Note that **you can also use the results of *expressions* as indices**; e.g., the equivalent of `$args[-1]` is `$args[$args.Count-1]` (assuming the array has at least one element).

Additionally, **you may specify *multiple* indices to extract a sub-array of arbitrary elements**. E.g., `$args[0, -1]` returns a (new) array comprising the input array's *first* and the *last* element (assuming the array has at least two elements).

**`..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-)** is particularly useful for **extracting a range of contiguous elements**. E.g., `$args[0..2]` returns a (new) array comprising the first 3 elements (the elements with indices `0`, `1`, and `2`).

You can even ***combine* individual indices with ranges**, courtesy of PowerShell's `+` operator performing (flat) array *concatenation*.
E.g., `$args[0..2 + -1]` extracts the first 3 elements as well as the last (assumes at least 4 elements).

- Note: For syntactic reasons, if a *single* index comes *first* in the index expression, you need to make it an *array* with the unary form of `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), to make sure that `+` performs *array* concatention; e.g., `$args[,-1 + 0..2]` extracts the last element followed by the first 3.

---

**Pitfall**: **Combining a *positive* `..` start point with a *negative* end point for up-to-the-last-Nth-element logic does *not* work as intended**:

Assume the following array:

```sh
$a = 'first', 'middle1', 'middle2', 'last'
```

It is tempting to use range expression `1..-2` to extract all elements "in the middle", i.e. starting with the 2nd and up to the penultimate element - but this does *not* work as expected:

```sh
# BROKEN attempt to extract 'middle1', 'middle2'
PS> $a[1..-2]
middle1
first
last
middle2
```

The reason is that `1..-2`, as a purely arithmetic range expression, expanded to the following array (whose elements *happen to be* used as indices into another array): `1, 0, -1, -2`. And it is these elements that were extracted: the 2nd, the first, the last, the penultimate.

To **avoid this problem, you need to know the array's *element count* ahead of time, and use an *expression* to specify the end of the range as a *positive* number**:

```sh
# OK: extract 'middle1', 'middle2'
# Note that the verbosity and the need to know $a's element count.
PS> $a[1..($a.Count-2)]
middle1
middle2
```

Unfortunately, this is both verbose and inconvenient, especially given that you may want to operate on a collection whose count you do *not* know in advance.

**[GitHub issue #7940](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7940) proposes a future enhancement to better support this use case with *new syntax***, analogous to [C#'s indices-and-ranges feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges), so that the above could be written more conveniently with syntax **such as `$a[1..^1]`**