# .Net Core sample powershell script example that take parameters

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I am trying to run sample powershell script from .net core application.
Basically i need to give parameters to script and utilized parameters inside script,but doesn't seem working.

```
static void Main() {
  string scriptContent = @ "param($SubscriptionId)
  Write-Host $SubscriptionId ";

  Dictionary < string, object > scriptParameters = new Dictionary < string, object > ();
  scriptParameters.Add("SubscriptionId", "sid");

  RunScript(scriptContent, scriptParameters);
}

public async Task RunScript(string scriptContents, Dictionary < string, object > scriptParameters) {
  // create a new hosted PowerShell instance using the default runspace.
  // wrap in a using statement to ensure resources are cleaned up.

  using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
    // specify the script code to run.
    ps.AddScript(scriptContents);

    // specify the parameters to pass into the script.
    ps.AddParameters(scriptParameters);

    // execute the script and await the result.
    var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // print the resulting pipeline objects to the console.
    foreach(var item in pipelineObjects) {
      Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

> sid

Any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add to Daniel's helpful answer:  [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)

Answer (score 1):

You C# code looks okay.  I believe the issue lies in your PowerShell script.  `Write-Host` sends string values to the information stream which will not populate into `pipelineObjects` (however you will find this output in `ps.Streams.Information`).  To write the `$SubscriptionId` to the pipeline and ultimately into your `pipelineObjects` collection just remove `Write - Host` (which has extra spaces in it anyways and would error).

```
static void Main() {
  string scriptContent = @"param($SubscriptionId) $SubscriptionId";

  Dictionary < string, object > scriptParameters = new Dictionary < string, object > ();
  scriptParameters.Add("SubscriptionId", "sid");

  RunScript(scriptContent, scriptParameters);
}
```