# Powershell invoke-sqlcmd Printing The Wrong Output

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a SQL query that is running as expected however when I try to use it in PowerShell 'Invoke-SqlCmd' module, the output comes out different than when querying the database. I noticed that there are quite a few questions regarding this module but I couldn't find one that is applicable to my case.

**Query:**

```
    $SQLServer = "localhost"
    $query = "SELECT Groups.[Name] AS AGname FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states States INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_groups Groups ON States.group_id = Groups.group_id WHERE primary_replica = @@Servername"

    $HAGName = Invoke-Sqlcmd  -query $query -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database 'database' 

    if ($HAGName = !$null) {
        
        write-host "Availability group name is $HAGName"
        exit 0
    }
    else {

        write-host "Failed to retrieve High Availability group name = [$HAGName]"
        exit 1
    }
```

**Output in PowerShell:** 'Availability group name is True'

Like I mentioned, when querying SQL Server directly I get the correct output. I tried using the 'OutputAs' switch but it didn't help.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be udner the impression that `Invoke-SqlCmd` returns `NULL` if no rows are returned; that isn't true. If the value of `$query` was `SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE 1 = 0;` then `$HAGName = !$null` would still be TRUE.

Comment: Mind that what you are doing is an *assignment*, I think you meant `$HAGName -ne $null`, but Larnu's comment still applies.

Comment: @Larnu, I am not by any stretch of the imagination a SQL person, this is the query I got from the company's senior DBAs so I tend to believe it should be solid. Can you please elaborate to me on what do you think is failing the command?

Comment: `-not $null` is `True` and you're assigning this to the variable `$HAGName` as others commented before. Replace `if ($HAGName = !$null) {` for `if ($null -ne $HAGName) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the pointers are in the comments on the question, but let me break it down systematically:

- `!$null` is *always* `$true` in PowerShell: `!` / `-not`, the [logical NOT operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators) coerces `$null` to a Boolean, and since `[bool] $null` is `$false`, `! $null` is `$true`.
- `$HAGName = !$null`, due to using `=`, the [assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators), therefore assigns `$true` to variable `$HAGName`.

  - To instead perform an equality *comparison*, use `-eq`, the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq).

Therefore, `$null -eq $HAGName` is what you meant to use (placing the `$null` on the *LHS*, for robustness - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq-and--ne)).

However, given PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean coercion rules (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375)), you could simplify to `if ($HAGName) { ... }` in this case.

Therefore, a *more* PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation of your code is:

```sh
$SQLServer = 'localhost'
$query = 'SELECT Groups.[Name] AS AGname FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states States INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_groups Groups ON States.group_id = Groups.group_id WHERE primary_replica = @@Servername'

$HAGName = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database database

if ($HAGName) {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Availability group name is: "
    # Output the System.Data.DataRow instance as-is,
    # which also results in proper for-display formatting.
    # If you just want the value of the .AGname property (column), use
    #  $HAGName.AGname instead.
    $HAGName 
    exit 0
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve High Availability group name."
    exit 1
}
```

Note:

- The success case *implicitly* outputs the result, to the *success output stream*.

  - [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)
  - I've used a [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) call (whose output is quiet by default, here I've used `-Verbose` to force it to show) to provide *optional* supplemental / status information.
  - `$HAGName` now (implicitly) outputs the `[System.Data.DataRow]` instance returned by the `Invoke-SqlCmd` call *as-is*, which also results in proper display formatting - such instances do *not* stringify meaningfully when used in an expandable (interpolating string); they unhelpfully stringify to their *type name*, i.e. to  verbatim `System.Data.DataRow`.

    - However, if you access a specific *property* (column) of the row, its value *may* stringify meaningfully, depending on *its* data type; in your case: `"Availability group name is $($HAGName.AGname)"
    - To include the usual for-display formatting inside a string - use something like `"Availability group name is $($HAGName | Out-String)"`