# Why does Write-Host not work when run in a powershell job?

Tags: powershell, jobs, write-host

Sorry if I'm being a dumb powershell noob, but what's wrong with jobs apparently being unable to write to the terminal? And how can I fix that?

```
# test.ps1
function myjob {
    Write-Host "Hello, World!" # doesn't show
}
Start-Job -Name MyJob -ScriptBlock ${function:myjob}
Wait-Job MyJob
Remove-Job MyJob
```

Comment: you need to receive the job - Get-Job |  Receive-Job

Comment: I've tried that, but all it does is yield a value returned by the job. That's definitly not what I want - my job routines are a bit more complex than the tiny example code I provided for the question...

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)

Comment: Hmm, weird. But yes it's working with Receive-Job added, even though the script block isn't supposed to return a value. And yes, my intent is to only show it on the console, so I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) to *directly, synchronously* write to the console (terminal) from a background job.

However, **PowerShell [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) do *not* allow direct access to the caller's console**.  *Any* output - even to the PowerShell *host* (which in *foreground* use is the console, if run in one) is routed through PowerShell's system of output streams (see the conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic).

Therefore, **you *always* need the [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) cmdlet in order to receive output** from a PowerShell job.

The following **example receives the job output *synchronously***, i.e. it *blocks execution* until the job finishes (`-Wait`) and then removes it (`-AutoRemoveJob`); see the bottom section for an *asynchronous* (polling, non-blocking) approach.

```
$null = Start-Job -Name MyJob -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "Hello, World!" } 
Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob -Name  MyJob
```

**Caveat re use of `Write-Host` in jobs**:

- In *foreground* use, `Write-Host` output - even though primarily designed to go to the *host* (console) - can be redirected or captured via the *information stream* (whose number is `6`, available in PSv5+); e.g.:

  ```
  # OK - no output
  Write-Host 'silence me' 6>$null
  ```
- `Write-Host` output received *via a (child-process-based) background job*, however, can *not* be redirected or captured, as of PowerShell 7.2.1:

  ```
  # !! `silence me` still prints. 
  Start-Job { Write-Host 'silence me' } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob 6>$null
  ```

  - By contrast, it *can* be redirected/captured when using a (generally preferable) *thread*-based background job (as opposed to a *child-process*-based background job), via [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob):

    ```
    # OK - no output
    Start-ThreadJob { Write-Host 'silence me' } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob 6>$null
    ```

---

**Waiting for a job to complete in a *non-blocking* fashion, passing job output through as it becomes available**:

```
# Start a simple job that writes a "." to the host once a second,
# for 5 seconds
$job = Start-Job $job -ScriptBlock { 
         1..5| ForEach-Object { Write-Host -NoNewLine .; Start-Sleep 1 } 
       } 

"Waiting for job $($job.Id) to terminate while passing its output through..."

do {
  $job | Receive-Job  # See if job output is available (non-blocking) and pass it through
  Start-Sleep 1       # Do other things or sleep a little.
} while (($job | Get-Job).State -in 'NotStarted', 'Running')

"`nJob terminated with state '$($job.State)'."

$job | Remove-Job     # Clean up.
```

- Note: In this simple case, the expected termination states are `Completed` (either no or only *non*-terminating errors occurred) or `Failed` (a script-terminating error was generated with `throw` (and not caught inside the job)).

  - See the [`[System.Management.Automation.JobState]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.jobstate) enumeration for the complete list of possible states.
- The job *object* returned by [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) - rather than a self-chosen name via the `-Name` parameter - is used to interact with the job. This eliminates the ambiguity of possibly *multiple* jobs being present with a given `-Name`, all of which would be targeted.

Comment: Thanks man, you're awesome! I think I can manage the rest from now on :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BinkanSalaryman; my pleasure.