# PowerShell script output redirection to file

Tags: powershell, line-breaks, write-host

when I run the script in the terminal without output redirection, everything looks fine.
But when I redirect to file, Write-Host -NoNewLine don't work (line is broken).

```
test.ps1 *>output.log
```

```
Write-Host "Hello " -nonewline; Write-Host " World"
```

Comment: This might also help: [Why does write host not work when run in a powershell job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724859/why-does-write-host-not-work-when-run-in-a-powershell-job)