# Unable to convert Yaml to Powershell Object

Tags: json, powershell, yaml

[image]

Above is variables.stg.yml

I am trying to read it in my Powershell code. I used   https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/powershell-yaml/0.4.2   for this

```
$os_list = (Get-Content -Raw -Path ..\variables.stg.yml| ConvertFrom-Yaml) 
$json = $os_list | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $json 
#Convert JSON file to an object
$JsonParameters = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
Write-Host $JsonParameters
#Create new PSObject with no properties
$oData = New-Object PSObject
#Loop through properties of the $JsonParameters.parameters object, and add them to the new blank object
$JsonParameters.parameters.psobject.Properties.Name | 
ForEach{ 
    Add-Member -InputObject $oData -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue 
$JsonParameters.parameters.$_.Value 
}

Write-Host $oData
```

However what i see is :

[image]

Comment: Why are you converting the data to json and back again? FWIW, the error seems to be cause by referencing `$JsonParameters.parameters` instead of `$JsonParameters.variables`

Comment: Write-Host $JsonParameters  is printing   @{variables=}

Comment: Exactly, so you want to do `$JsonParameters.variables.psobject.Properties.Name | ForEach-Object { ...` - not `$JsonParameters.parameters.psobject.Properties.Name | ForEach-Object { ...` (or perhaps just `$oData = $JsonParameters.parameters` if you're not going to use/modify `$JsonParameters` any further anyway)

Comment: Have you tried making `$oData = New-Object PSObject` a `PSCustomObject` ?

Comment: Its slightly unclear what you are aiming to do.  The idea proposed by Mathias is what you're looking for - assuming you know that "variables" is the parent level item in the yaml, always.

I see that the initial yaml import is coming in as a hashtable - I assume that's why you're converting to json - but you can also just create your psobject there:  [PSCustomObject]$os_list

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375). To explicitly print only to the display _but with rich formatting_, use `Out-Host`.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem with your code is that you're referencing `$JsonParameter.parameters` when you really want `$JsonParameters.variables` - the property name in the yaml file is `variables`, not `parameters`.

A less cumbersome way to obtain an object with the `ABC` and `Test` entries from the yaml file as properties would be to simply cast the hashtable generated by `ConvertTo-Yaml` to a `[PSCustomObject]`:

```
$documentWithVariables = Get-Content -Path ..\variables.stg.yml -Raw |ConvertFrom-Yaml 
$oData = [PSCustomObject]$documentWithVariables.variables
```

Much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use Convertto-YAML to converted to serialized JSON.

Accordding to [their documentation](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml#converting-from-yaml-to-json) you need to use the `jsoncompatible` flag to do this.

### Converting from YAML to JSON

> The awesome YamlDotNet assembly allows us to serialize an object in a
> JSON compatible way. Unfortunately it does not support indentation.
> Here is a simple example:

```
Import-Module powershell-yaml

PS C:\> $yaml = @"
anArray:
- 1
- 2
- 3
nested:
  array:
  - this
  - is
  - an
  - array
hello: world
"@

PS C:\> $obj = ConvertFrom-Yaml $yaml
PS C:\> $obj

Name                           Value
----                           -----
anArray                        {1, 2, 3}
nested                         {array}
hello                          world

PS C:\> ConvertTo-Yaml -JsonCompatible $obj
{"anArray": [1, 2, 3], "nested": {"array": ["this", "is", "an", "array"]}, "hello": "world"}

# Or you could do it in one line.
PS C:\> ConvertFrom-Yaml $yaml | ConvertTo-Yaml -JsonCompatible
{"anArray": [1, 2, 3], "nested": {"array": ["this", "is", "an", "array"]}, "hello": "world"}
```

Your array is also not formatted correctly to be imported as a nested. Below is correct syntax:

```
variables:
 ABC: 
  XYz
 Test: 
  preprod01
```

Finally:

```
[pscustomobject]$os_list = (ConvertFrom-Yaml -yaml (get-content -Raw C:\Powershell\TestCSVs\variables.stg.yml))
[pscustomobject]$os_list = ConvertTo-Yaml $os_list -JsonCompatible
$os_list

$oData = $os_list.variables
$oData


PS:> {"variables": {"ABC": "XYz", "Test": "preprod01"}}
```