# Powershell ConvertTo-Json adding many spaces between characters

Tags: powershell, formatting, convertto-json

I've got issue on following script. I am using latest PowerShell 7

Code:

```
$databasesArray = @('Zero','One','Two','Three')

$databasesDev = $databasesArray | ConvertTo-Json -Compress 
Write-Host @databasesDev
```

Result:

> [ " Z e r o " , " O n e " , " T w o " , " T h r e e " ]

Expected:

> ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"]

How to fix it? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `Write-Host @databaseDev` -> `Write-Host $databaseDev` :)

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g, `$value`, instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375). To explicitly print only to the display _but with rich formatting_, use `Out-Host`.

Answer (score 4):

`ConvertTo-Json` isn't adding any space.

The splat operator `@` will take any dictionary or array and "explode" the contained values against the target command.

In this case, the array being splatted simply happens to be a string, meaning you're effectively feeding `Write-Host` each character in the string as a separate positional argument.

You can observe the same behavior with *any string*:

```
$Text = "Hello Tomasz!"
Write-Host @Text
```

Which will print out:

```
H e l l o   T o m a s z !
```

So to fix your issue, simple stop using `@`:

```
# this will give print the result you want
Write-Host $databaseDev
```