# Powershell: How to print list items in 1 string

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, concatenation

Let's say i have this code:

```
$test = @("apple" , "orange", "pear")
```

If i do `write-host $test[0]` i will get `apple` returned.

If i do `write-host $test[0] $test[1] $test[2]` i will get this returned:

```
apple
orange
pear
```

When i try getting in 1 line as just a single string I am doing:

```
write-host "$test[0] $test[1] $test[2]"
```

But this returns:

```
apple orange pear[0] apple orange pear[1] apple orange pear[2]
```

It can't seem to recognise the index now that i Have added quotations

**Question:**

Anyone know how i can just get my result to look like:

```
"apple orange pear"
```

Note: i do need to wrap this in quotations as i will be using it a script elsewhere which would require this - this is just a simple example for what i need

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Abdul's [excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153561/712649) of using `-join`, you can also use the `$OFS` (short for **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator) automatic variable to control how PowerShell expands arrays in string literals:

```
PS ~> $test = @("apple" , "orange", "pear")
PS ~> $OFS = ' '
PS ~> "$test"
apple orange pear
PS ~> $OFS = '-'
PS ~> "$test"
apple-orange-pear
PS ~> $OFS = '/'
PS ~> "$test"
apple/orange/pear
```

If left unset, a single space character will be used as the default separator:

```
PS ~> $OFS = $null
PS ~> "$test"
apple orange pear
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to join the array elements by a space.

```
Write-Host ($test -Join " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the existing, helpful answers:

- [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g, `$value`, instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375). To explicitly print only to the display *but with rich formatting*, use `Out-Host`.
- If you *are* using `Write-Host` deliberately, you can take advantage of the fact that it *implicitly* stringifies arrays by space-concatenating their elements; note that a space is *invariably* used in this case; that is, the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs) does *not* apply:

  ```
  $test = @("apple" , "orange", "pear")

  Write-Host $test # -> 'apple orange pear'
  ```
- If, by contrast, you want to output the string as *data*, just use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), as explained in [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153626/45375) - as noted, you can use `$OFS` to change to a separator other than a space, but note that (a) `$OFS` is rarely used in practice and (b) it is important to restore it to its previous value after changing it, so as not to affect unrelated code.

  ```
  # Note: The resulting string is *implicitly* output and prints
  #       to the display by default.
  #       The verbose equivalent would be
  #          Write-Output "$test"
  "$test"  # -> 'apple orange pear'
  ```
- If you need more explicit - and side-effect-free - control over how an array is stringified, use the [`-join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator, as shown in [Abdul Niyas P M's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153561/45375).

---

Finally, as for **what you tried**:

> `write-host "$test[0] $test[1] $test[2]"`

**Embedding *expressions* such as `$test[0]` in `"..."`** rather than _stand-alone variable references such as just `$test` **requires use of `$(...)`**, the [subexpression operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) - without it, `"$test[0]"` expands `$test` *as a whole* - ironically resulting in the desired whole-array stringification you sought after all - and treats `[0]` as a *verbatim* part of the string.
This is a common pitfall; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1145704/45375) for more information.

Therefore, what you needed was - note the `$(...)`:

```
Write-Host "$($test[0]) $($test[1]) $($test[2])" # -> 'apple orange pear'
```

Comment: thank you! Useful to know - especially the last part to show why mine didn't work

Comment: Glad to hear it, @polo.