# Two PowerShell methods: SetString() accept a string from the user and PrintString() print the string in upper case

Tags: powershell

1. What can I do so that I write the desired phrase in brackets and it will be accepted?
2. Where exactly to get the "basis" in order to make a return using the "PrintString" method?

```
# Example 1
$Object.SetString("gamarjoba")
# Example 2
$Object.PrintString()
# Returns
GAMARJOBA
```

Here is one of my attempts:

```
class Object {
[string]$gamarjoba

[string]SetString() {
    return Write-Host "gamarjoba"
}

[string]PrintString() {
    return Write-Host "gamarjoba".ToUpper()
}

}
```

I understand that this is a very basic question, but I have already spent too much time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

```bash
class MyObject {

  [string] $gamarjoba = ''  # instance variable

  # Method has no return type; accepts a string parameter
  # and assigns it to instance variable $this.gamarjoba
  [void] SetString([string] $gamarjoba) {
    $this.gamarjoba = $gamarjoba
  }
  
  # Returns the uppercased form of the $this.gamarjoba instance variable.
  # Do NOT use Write-Host.
  [string] PrintString() {
    return $this.gamarjoba.ToUpper()
  }
  
}

$obj = [MyObject]::new() # create an instance
$obj.SetString('aha')    # set the string
$obj.PrintString()       # print the uppercased string
```

Note that I've named the class `MyObject`, because `Object` would clash with the root class of the .NET type hierarchy.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `return Write-Host "gamarjoba".ToUpper()`

- Fundamentally, **do NOT use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) to return or output *data*** - it is meant for printing information to the *display* (console), and bypasses the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) and thereby the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for more information.
- In the context of **`class`** definitions, **use *only* `return` to return data from a method**, **passing it an *expression* or *command* *as-is*** (e.g, `return 'foo'.ToUpper()` or `return Get-Date -Format yyy`)

**PowerShell [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)es participate in the system of [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) only in a very limited way**:

- [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return)ing a value from a method writes it to the success output stream.

  - Notably, *implicit* output and use of [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) (i.e. what you would use in a *script* or *function*) are *not* supported and quietly ignored. (While you can use `return Write-Output ...`, there's no good reason to do so.)
- [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw)ing an error writes it to the error stream - but you'll only see that if you catch or silence such a fatal-by-default error.

  - Notably, using [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error) to write *non-terminating* errors does *not* work and is quietly ignored.
- However, you *can* write to all *other* output streams using their respective `Write-*` cmdlets, such as `Write-Warning`.